# Cmake is unable to find boost_pyhton libraries in Homebrew

Tags: homebrew, boost-python, cmake-modules

I am trying to build a C++ code on Mac. I am using CMake for my setup. This is my file (note, I get an error with python3.7, python37, python, but more on that below):

```
    find_package(Boost COMPONENTS python3.7)
    message("Includes: ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${Python3_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
```

I get the following error:

```
-- Found Boost 1.71.0 at /usr/local/lib/cmake/Boost-1.71.0
--   Requested configuration: QUIET COMPONENTS python3.7
-- BoostConfig: find_package(boost_headers 1.71.0 EXACT CONFIG  QUIET HINTS /usr/local/lib/cmake)
-- Found boost_headers 1.71.0 at /usr/local/lib/cmake/boost_headers-1.71.0
-- BoostConfig: find_package(boost_python3.7 1.71.0 EXACT CONFIG  QUIET HINTS /usr/local/lib/cmake)
-- Could NOT find Boost: missing: python3.7 (found /usr/local/lib/cmake/Boost-1.71.0/BoostConfig.cmake (found version "1.71.0"))
Includes: /usr/local/include /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m
```

I am using the latest Homebrew

```
brew --version
Homebrew 2.1.12
Homebrew/homebrew-core (git revision 5b0c; last commit 2019-10-06)
```

And have loaded the available boost formulae.

```
brew list | grep boost
boost
boost-python
boost-python3
```

Looking under `/usr/local/lib/cmake/` I see most of the boost libraries mentioned, but boost_python and boost_numpy are missing. I checked the online formulae definitions and `boost` does indeed include all the cmake setups in that directory, but `boost_python3` does not include any.

Am I missing some package? Is there a portable way to setup this so that it automatically finds the libboost_python37.* files?

Answer (score 1):

Because there is no `python3.7` component. This component is called [`python37`, at least for CMake 3.16 and earlier](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.16/module/FindBoost.html?highlight=python):

> Note that Boost Python components require a Python version suffix (Boost 1.67 and later), e.g. python36 or python27 for the versions built against Python 3.6 and 2.7, respectively. This also applies to additional components using Python including mpi_python and numpy. Earlier Boost releases may use distribution-specific suffixes such as 2, 3 or 2.7. These may also be used as suffixes, but note that they are not portable